# jQuery sortable keep table's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Couldn't find a simple solution for jquery's sortable to keep width of table during dragging element, forcePlaceholderSize is not actually working this time, if table have some large element - if i start dragging it then the table resized to still-in-table element's max width, so here is what I've done:

```
jQuery("#sortable1").sortable({
    items: "tbody:not([not-sortable])",
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 9999,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var colW = jQuery(".faq_glyph_owner").width();
        self.textWidth = ui.item.innerWidth() - colW * 3;
        jQuery(".faq_text").width(self.textWidth);
        jQuery("#sortable1").css("table-layout", "fixed");
        ui.item.find("div").parent().width(self.textWidth + colW);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery("#sortable1").css("table-layout", "auto");
    }
});
```

So i'm generally just counting size as it supposed to be and apply fixed layout to table, [here is sample of this with table](https://jsfiddle.net/pba2df1b/). So my question is : **Is there any built-in ways to keep table width during sorting, as if dragged element is still inside table?** Please note that i do not want to keep table's layout fixed.

P.S. please ignore 'jQuery', we just still have legacy prototype code that interferes with it

Comment: What you already have is the most straightforward way of achieving this behaviour. The `forcePlaceholderSize` option will only set the placeholder's size if it's non-visible otherwise (ie. it's a 0-width rectangle, which, here, it isn't). If you want to be thorough, create a new widget, inheriting from sortable, and write a custom placeholder, but that's a lot of additional work for a similar effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
        items: "tbody:not([not-sortable])",
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: "move",
        zIndex: 9999,
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.item[0]).show().css('opacity','0');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.item[0]).css('opacity','1');
        }
    });
```

You are basically cloning the element and instead of hiding it whilst moving, you just apply `opacity` of 0 and then applying `opacity` of 1 once dropped. I didn't really have time to test it.

Comment: This is really great idea, tested a bit and it is working, just have to make some changes for it to be completely fitting(right now this element while having opacity of 0, still have borders), i'll mark you answer as right as soon as manage to create a fiddle with everything working perfectly

Answer (score 8):

```
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {  
  ui.children().each(function() {  
  console.log(e);
    $(this).width($(this).width());  
  });  
  return ui;  
};

$("#sortable1 tbody").sortable({  
    helper: fixHelper  
}).disableSelection();
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pba2df1b/35/)

[Source article](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but code above doesn't work as expected if specify sorting by #sortable(which is required) and not #sortable tbody(which limits dragging to one tbody, and therefore require additional connectTo), and also table still collapse(at least at the first drag). its only rows which are not collapsed

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use for this.  I create a helper function that gets the height and width of everything in the row and then explicitly sets it to those heights and widths, plus adds a row back in as a placeholder.

```
var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
            fixHelper(e, $(this));
        }
        if(parseInt($(this).css("margin-left")) != 0)
            $(this).css("margin-left", $(this).css("margin-left"));

        if (parseInt($(this).css("margin-right")) != 0)
            $(this).css("margin-right", $(this).css("margin-right"));

        $(this).width($(this).realWidth(true));
        $(this).height($(this).realHeight(true));
    });

    ui.height(ui.realHeight());
    return ui;
};

var unfixHelper = function (ui) {
    ui.children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
            unfixHelper($(this));
        }
        $(this).css("margin-left", "");
        $(this).css("margin-right", "");
        $(this).css("width", "");
        $(this).css("height", "");
    });
    ui.css("height", "");
};


var sortableOptions = new Object({
    items: "tbody:not([not-sortable])",
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 9999,
    helper: fixHelper,
    start: function (e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
        ui.placeholder.html("<td colspan=\"10\">&nbsp;</td>");
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        unfixHelper(ui.item);
        ui.placeholder.html("");
    }   
});

jQuery("#sortable1").sortable(sortableOptions);
```

Another file (real-dimensions.js):

```
$.fn.realWidth = function (inner) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    var width;
    if (rect.width) {
        // `width` is available for IE9+
        width = rect.width;

    } else {
        // Calculate width for IE8 and below
        width = rect.right - rect.left;
    }

    if (inner)
        width -= parseInt($t.css("padding-left")) + parseInt($t.css("padding-right"));

    return width;
}

$.fn.realHeight = function (inner) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    var height;
    if (rect.height) {
        // `height` is available for IE9+
        height = rect.height;
    } else {
        // Calculate height for IE8 and below
        height = rect.top - rect.bottom;
    }

    if (inner)
        height -= parseInt($t.css("padding-top")) + parseInt($t.css("padding-bottom"));

    return height;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is great, but it still use some calculations, so I cannot accept it as answer, because I was wondering if there is some built-in possibilities to achieve the same results, maybe I should specify this in question, thank you

Comment: Allow me to assure you, this *is* the answer.  There are no built in ways to accomplish this.  Any "built-in" ways would also use calculations.

Comment: There is more complicated code that finds out the *real* height and width (allowing for decimals) using javascript's built-in function `.getBoundingClientRect()` (.width / .height) that I also use.  I call them `realWidth()` and `realHeight()`.

Comment: I insist that it's not the answer I asked, for I already have a way of doing the same things even in less code, it is just there in my question and what i'm really looking for is for simple solution, that will not require any additional knowledge about DOM element being sortable. If there is no such - then this question have no answer, but still it doesn't make your answer the thing I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called [**helper**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) in the sortable widget. Its purpose is to add some behaviour to the dragging display action.
The relevant part of the modification is:

```
jQuery('#sortable1').sortable({
    helper: fixedWidth
});

function fixedWidth(e, ui) {
    var max_w = 0;
    // get the max width from all the children
    ui.children().each(function() {
        var w = $(this).width();
        if (w > max_w) max_w = w;
    });
    // set the width of the table to be the max
    $('#sortable1').width(max_w);
    return ui; 
}
```

A full implementation can be found in this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pba2df1b/1/). I got inspiration from this [blog](https://paulund.co.uk/fixed-width-sortable-tables).

Also, if you mind my opinion, I would build this structure in a simpler way, using `<ul>` instead of `<table>`. Like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/4kuuh48u/). You only have to style the `<ul>` in order to have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

1. add colgroup to table tag

```
    <colgroup>
       <col style="width: 0%"/>
       <col style="width: 0%"/>
       <col style="width: 100%"/>
       <col style="width: 0%"/>
    </colgroup>
```

2. set width in 'table'

```
    table {
      border-collapse : collapse;
      width: 550px;
    }
```